# The procedure entry point could not be located in the dynamic link library in deep learning

Tags: python-3.x, deep-learning, recurrent-neural-network

I get an error in my project (link below)

## Movie-Review-Sentiment-Analysis

Sentiment Analysis using Recursive Neural Network.
This is the relevant part of my code:

```
hidden_layer = tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(hidden_layer_size)
hidden_layer = tf.contrib.rnn.DropoutWrapper(hidden_layer, dropout_rate)
cell = tf.contrib.rnn.MultiRNNCell([hidden_layer]*number_of_layers)
init_state = cell.zero_state(batch_size, tf.float32)
```

But I get this error:

> NotFoundError:
> C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\contrib\image\python\ops_distort_image_ops.so not found
> tensorflow\contrib\coder\python\ops_coder_ops.so not found

When I am going to execute this above code, I get a Python Event Message Box that shows

> the procedure entry point could do not located in dynamic link library in deep learning

I run [this code from GitHUB](https://github.com/kshitij1210/Movie-Review-Sentiment-Analysis).

Comment: any one try this i need output

Answer (score 0):

If someone is still trying to find the answer to this problem,
Try to edit the code like this

```
hidden_layer = tf.nn.rnn_cell.BasicLSTMCell(hidden_layer_size)
hidden_layer = tf.nn.rnn_cell.DropoutWrapper(hidden_layer, dropout_rate)
cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.MultiRNNCell([hidden_layer]*number_of_layers)
```